# Angular Microfrontends and PWAs

Tags: angular, progressive-web-apps

I am struggling with **microfrontend*** and **PWA** with cooperation together.
I have 2 apps. Shell and Remote.
Shell dynamically load this remote app content when user click in navigation on "remote" link.

Anyways, my question. I configured PWA for shell app. When I change the code, app will notificate user, so there is a change.
Is here some simple way, how can I notificate also shell app with changes on remote app?

I was trying something like this, in ngsw-config.json but without success.
I need maybe only some push to correct solution, if there is someone who was solving this kind of issue. (notify child - MF to parent- MF about change with PWA)

[image]

Comment: Solved: Angular doesnt support this kind of functionality.